# i am locked out of my android after forgetting the pattern

Tags: locked-out

I forgot the lock pattern to my android zte groove and the phone has locked me out.  I attempted to use my google email as it requests and it still won't let me in.  Is there anyway to unlock my phone?

Comment: What happens if you try to unlock the device with your google mail account?

Comment: [comment by Psb] If you are unable to open the lock via `gmail username-password` facility; then I suggest that you go to nearest Service center. They shall mostly format it! Either way, you shall lose data...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at the bottom it should say "unlock by email" and type in your gmail account that you set your phone up to and voila it should be unlocked. And then change your password in the settings